# Slow directory listing when browsing Windows share

Tags: networking, mount, cifs

We have a Linux client using mount cifs -t and browsing between the directories is extremely slow, sometimes 1-3 minutes just to list the folders.

The share resides on a Windows server.  Windows clients don't have this issue.

We can reproduce the issue if we install a new version of Ubuntu on a VM.

One thing to note is that this user is connecting over MPLS from a remote office to our datacenter over a 100 Mbps connection.

The latency is 50 ms.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue?  Suggestions?

We originally had issues with performance locked at 1 MB/sec for transfer rate; however, if we added vers=3.02 to the mount cifs command the transfer rate is able to go up to 11 Mb/sec.

The only issue left is the laggy switching between folders.

If we run ls from the terminal it has the same lag, sometimes 2 minutes to show the ls listing.

If we run sudo ls the directory list is instant, not sure why or if there is anything we can do to mitigate the issue.

Running ls -R really shows the issue.. sudo ls -R is basically almost instant.

If we setup another map to a different location on our MPLS network with 25 ms latency, the issue is gone and browsing is instant.

Help please.

Comment: Does using the `--numeric-uid-gid` (or `-n`) parameter to `ls` affect runtime? Can you run `journalctl --follow` in another window as you `ls`? Can you run `wireshark` and see how many TCP/IP packlets are caused by `ls`?

Comment: --numeric-uid-gid or -n didn't make a difference

journalctl doesn't appear to throw out any errors that indicate an issue.  The affected system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: if I use /bin/ls it works fine, but no colors, just plain text

Browsing with Files GUI is also very slow.

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

type ls results in:  ls is aliased to 'ls --color=auto'

Comment: Use `wireshark` to see what differs between "Running ls -R really shows the issue.. sudo ls -R is basically almost instant". What packets, which protocols, what packet timing, network overhead protocols (`DNS`,...), are there retries?

Comment: I'll give wireshark a shot next week.

Answer (score 0):

The full `ls` documentation (`info '(coreutils) ls invocation'` or [the online version](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html#General-output-formatting)), has a probable solution:

```
 Note that using the ‘--color’ option may incur a noticeable
 performance penalty when run in a directory with very many entries,
 because the default settings require that ‘ls’ ‘stat’ every single
 file it lists.  However, if you would like most of the file-type
 coloring but can live without the other coloring options (e.g.,
 executable, orphan, sticky, other-writable, capability), use
 ‘dircolors’ to set the ‘LS_COLORS’ environment variable like this,
      eval $(dircolors -p | perl -pe \
        's/^((CAP|S[ET]|O[TR]|M|E)\w+).*/$1 00/' | dircolors -)
 and on a ‘dirent.d_type’-capable file system, ‘ls’ will perform
 only one ‘stat’ call per command line argument.
```

If you add network overhead to `stat`ting everything in the whole directory, your delay starts to become understandable.

Or, you could use an invocation of `ls` with `--color=off`, or no `--color`.

Comment: Tested some more
RHEL Server with desktop option, ls with colors is instant
RHEL Workstation, Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenSUSE all out of box, same thing ls with color is 20+seconds delay

I ran type ls on server version and it matches the other distros

Mapping through GUI is still very slow even if using the server ISO for RHEL.

I'm not sure why ls with colors would behave differently from server to workstation edition of RHEL.

Any ideas?  Or how to speed up the GUI?